# redraw GUI on didreceivelocalnotification when come from lock screen iphone

Tags: ios4, uilocalnotification, lockscreen

How do I prevent my GUI from redraw when it comes back from lock screen after receiving a UILocalNotification? In didReceiveLocalNotification I present a modal view, but the old state of my view controllers is shown for a moment before that. How do I prevent this?

Also the order of events I get when I come back on local notification from background is as following:

```
1. UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
2. UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
3. didReceiveLocalNotification
```

When I come from lock screen:

```
1. didReceiveLocalNotification
2. UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
```

Why is this difference and whether there is something else I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it was solved. May be it's not the way, but it worked for me. Since my application is voip/audio, it doesn't come to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`... I found out, that iOS uses a cached image from a previous state for animation when it resumes from background or from sleep mode. So the solution is basically to exchange this cached image with my default.png image. I do it in `applicationWillResignActive` delegate. There I add a modal view with a `Default.png` picture and dismiss it in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. This is really in short. Hopefully it will help somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom image that is displayed when launching/resuming from a local notification.  Simply set the `alertLaunchImage` property on your local notification to the name of the correct image.

From the Docs:

> The string is a filename of an image file in the application bundle. This image is a launching image specified for a given notification; when the user taps the action button (for example, “View”) or moves the action slider, the image is used in place of the default launching image. If the value of this property is nil (the default), the system either uses the previous snapshot, uses the image identified by the UILaunchImageFile key in the application’s Info.plist file, or falls back to Default.png.

[alertLaunchImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertLaunchImage)

Comment: I use @"Default.png", but seems it's being ignored. Somehow it shows previous views (or redraws them). I'm really don't know how to catch it.